navigation inside custom framework made with swiftui
I am creating a custom framework in SwiftUI that will have navigation between screens. The application implementing it will have navigation too, how can i avoid duplicate navigation scenario in the application and in the application.
In frameworks make with UIKit it is possible to access the navigation of the application and push your viewcontrollers on it BUT not sure how can it be achieved with SwiftUI

You could require that a binding to a NavigationPath is supplied to your framework. This would let you share the NavigationStack from the calling context.
The framework does not actually need a handle to the path for the links to work, but it does need to be sure that a path exists in the parent. So by requiring it to be passed, it forces the parent to use a NavigationPath for its navigation. Having it available also allows the framework to navigate back by popping the last destination, such as in button callbacks.
struct Framework: View {
    @Binding var navPath: NavigationPath

    enum LocalNavDestination {
        case view1
        case view2
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 40) {
            NavigationLink("Go to view1", value: LocalNavDestination.view1)
            NavigationLink("Go to view2", value: LocalNavDestination.view2)
            Button("Back to Home") {
                navPath.removeLast()
            }
            .padding(.top, 60)
        }
        .buttonStyle(.bordered)
        .navigationTitle("Framework")
        .navigationDestination(for: LocalNavDestination.self) { dest in
            switch dest {
            case .view1:
                Text("View1")
            case .view2:
                Text("View2")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()

    enum NavDestination {
        case localContent
        case framework
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            VStack(spacing: 40) {
                NavigationLink("Go to local content", value: NavDestination.localContent)
                NavigationLink("Go to framework", value: NavDestination.framework)
            }
            .buttonStyle(.bordered)
            .navigationTitle("Home")
            .navigationDestination(for: NavDestination.self) { dest in
                switch dest {
                case .localContent:
                    Text("Local content")
                case .framework:
                    Framework(navPath: $path)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


